# Set group label in pinned row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on the ag-grid application in which I want to display multiple calculated rows (similiar to 'totals' row, but with custom formulas). I did not find a better way to do this than by using pinned rows.
The problem is that when the grid has grouping applied, I cannot find a way to set a value of the empty 'grouping' cell in the pinned row which would serve as a metric label.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGEtj.jpg) is what I want to achieve.

I am aware that grouping is not supported in the pinned rows, but in this case pinned row is not grouped - in contrast to the actual grid.

I tried to do this through cell formatters/renderers as well as different data bindings but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually ended up using valueGetter in the autoGroupColumnDef.

```
autoGroupColumnDef: {
   valueGetter: params => params.data.metricName
}
```